# How to make Lombok generate multiple alias getters and fully capitalize abbreviated words?

Tags: java, javabeans, lombok, pojo

I am defining some the components of the ICCID in the field of telecommunications. Show my code:

```
@Data
public class IssuerIdentificationNumber {

    private MajorIndustryIdentifier mii;

    private CountryCallingCode countryCode;

    private IssuerIdentifier issuerId;

}
```

Lombok generated the `getMii()` method for me, but I want two equivalent getter methods named `getMII()` and `getMajorIndustryIdentifier()`. Is there a way to make Lombok do this?

like:

```
    ...

    @Getter(methodNames = ["getMII", "getMajorIndustryIdentifier"])
    private MajorIndustryIdentifier mii;

    ...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/836) related to this, but seems the team is not going to implement this. Seems the easiest way is to add `getMajorIndustryIdentifier` manually